# Is a special charger required for Li-ION battery packs with a BMS?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am replacing the lead acid batteries in an electric scooter and a kids electric motorcycle, in addition to building a 48V eBike battery pack.

The (3) units require 24v, 36v & 48v respectively so I'm building 14.8v battery packs that I can wire in series for each of them and will be using a 4S 40A battery monitoring system (BMS) on each battery module (see: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07RPW8MM6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RPW8MM6))

Can I put these 14.8V packs in series & use the scooter's existing 24V charger & the electric motorcycle (Razor MX650) 36V charger to charge them?

Or do I still need a special Lithium aware battery charger for each?

Comment: Yes, you need a lithium-ion charger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no for your charger.
If you know the maximum intake of your in series connected pack you can use a regular psu.
But, it ***must*** cut off at the reached voltige...avoid a float charge.
You can also use a buck converter.

You can not use your 24v psu, simply the numbers won't add up, or you burn them or they won't charge.

Add up what you want to charge in series totally.

To give you a exact answer i would (must) like to know more about your batteries.

Comment: The individual cells would be 3.5 amp hour 18650 Li-Ion batteries. The idea being that I would standardize on replacing each 12V lead acid battery with a Li-Ion 12-14.8V bundle of the 18650 cells with a 4P 4S configuration, with charging & discharging going through the BMS board listed in the question. I'm trying to determine if the BMS is providing the cut-off intelligence needed by the 12-14.8V packs, thus allowing me to just use the non-Lithium battery chargers (one 24V, one 36V & one 48V) to charge the appropriate number of these in series (2, 3 & 4)?